# Login error (302) when task added to queue with backend target

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a pretty simple application.  One of the things I do is when someone creates a new widget, I add a task to a task queue to get a qr code image for the widget and save it in the blob.

I have a queue defined as:

```
queue:  
- name: workqueue  
  target: worker  
  rate: 5/s
```

I have a backend defined as:

```
backends:
- name: worker
  options: dynamic
  class: B1
```

snippet of app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /tasks/fetchimage
script: worker.py
login: admin
```

In my code, when the user creates the widget the following is called:

```
        taskqueue.add(#queue_name="workqueue", 
                      url="/tasks/fetchimage",
                      method="GET", 
                      params={"design_id": design_id})
```

With "queue_name="workqueue" commented out, everything works fine (uses the default queue which does not go to the backend).  If I remove the comment, I get the following error in the logs:

> 0.1.0.2 - - [04/Jan/2012:19:05:29 -0800] "GET /tasks/fetchimage?design_id=9034 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
>   ...
>
> Request failed because URL requires user login. For requests invoked within App Engine (offline requests like Task Queue, or webhooks like XMPP and Incoming Mail), the URL must require admin login (or no login).

Am I missing something?  I assume app.yaml settings apply to backends.  Is this assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `login: admin` from the backend handler, and make sure the backend is private if you don't want users to be able to access that url.

See the [backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Public_and_Private_Backends) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I thought you made backend handler private by adding `login: admin` to the handler.  The backend is private by default.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Oh, and another thing.  I removed `login: admin` to test, it didn't help.

Comment: I hadn't realized that the backend had to be updated seperately from the rest of the application.  I thought you "updated" the backend once (to create) and every subsequent appcfg update would update both the front and back.  Once I updated the back things started working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: _The backend is private by default_: by default only your app can make request to the backend (not users) unless it is marked explicitly as public.